# How many languages are there in Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who

How many alien languages are shown in Doctor Who that somebody could learn, in the whole twelve Doctors? The only one I know of is Judoon.

Comment: Language is rarely dealt with in Doctor Who due to the Tardis'plot contrivance.. I mean magic! which translates all languages. Presumably there's at least one for every species, probably hundreds depending on how far back the history of it goes.

Comment: @MrLore It's not magic, it's just [sufficiently advanced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws). ; )

Comment: There’s also [baby](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWK61bkQ-ME&feature=kp) and [horse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdKAxu79FdA&feature=kp).

Comment: @MrLore not all languages, just most (See impossible planet and A Good man Goes to War)

Comment: +1 Not sure why this was downvoted, maybe someone could explain?

Comment: There are none. Judoon as presented is just random sounds. It's not a real constructed language.

Answer (score 2):

I have to highly doubt whether there will be many if any (I would go for none) as the writers decided long ago to not create Alien Languages (I say decided, I mean they created a Mechanic to prevent the need).

You may notice how many Aliens speak English this is because the TARDIS translates languages for anyone who has travelled within it as long as the doctor is awake (or at least for that one episode, Doctor Who continuity and all). We do get *snippets* of some Languages but there are not to my knowledge any **complete*** Alien Languages developed for Doctor Who.

*By complete I mean complete as to the same degree as let's say Klingon or Elven*

Comment: Jadoon Is Speakable. It is used when the Doctor goes to the Shadow Proclamation with Diana when the earth disappears.

Comment: It just takes longer to speak then English. Hello - (Ho Flo Lo Lo Plo)

Comment: @Baker When you said speakable I assumed you meant that you would be able to learn it from it's scope in doctor who. Technically you could speak baby you just wouldn't make any sense.